# ArcGIS highlight a graphic

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

in my program I have created polygons on a graphicsLayer from coordinates on my mapView. When I hover over a polygon, I want to highlight that polygon with orange color.

```
require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/Graphic",
        "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
        "esri/widgets/Search",
        "dojo/dom",
        "esri/renderers/UniqueValueRenderer",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol"
    ], function (Map, MapView, Graphic, GraphicsLayer, Search, dom, UniqueValueRenderer, SimpleLineSymbol) {
        map = new Map({
            basemap: "streets-navigation-vector"
        });
        var center = app.addresses[0].center;
        view = new MapView({
            container: "viewDiv",
            map: map,
            center: center, // longitude, latitude
            zoom: 15,
            highlightOptions: {
                color: "orange"
            }
        });



        var search = new Search({
            view: view,
            container: "search"
        });
        graphicsLayer = new GraphicsLayer();

        map.add(graphicsLayer);
        var i = 0;
        app.addresses.forEach(function (address) {
            var polygon = {
                type: "polygon",
                rings: address.polygon_rings
            };

            address.polygonGraphic = new Graphic({
                geometry: polygon,
                symbol: address.parking_zone
            });

            graphicsLayer.add(address.polygonGraphic);
            i++;
        });

        view.on("click", function(event){
            var screenPoint = {
                x: event.x,
                y: event.y
            };

            view.hitTest(screenPoint).then(function (response) {
                if (response.results.length) {
                    var graphic = response.results.filter(function (result) {
                        // check if the graphic belongs to the layer of interest
                        return result.graphic.layer === graphicsLayer;
                    })[0].graphic;
                    // do something with the result graphic
                    ToggleSelectedAddress(parseInt(graphic.uid));
                }
            });
        });

        view
            .when()
            .then(function() {
                return graphicsLayer.when();
            })
            .then(function(layer) {
                // Set up an event handler for pointer-down (mobile)
                // and pointer-move events (mouse)
                // and retrieve the screen x, y coordinates
                return view.whenLayerView(layer);
            })
            .then(function(layerView) {
                view.on("pointer-move", eventHandler);
                view.on("pointer-down", eventHandler);

                function eventHandler(event) {
                    // the hitTest() checks to see if any graphics in the view
                    // intersect the x, y coordinates of the pointer
                    view.hitTest(event).then(getGraphics);
                }

                let highlight;

                function getGraphics(response) {
                    // the topmost graphic from the hurricanesLayer
                    // and display select attribute values from the
                    // graphic to the user
                    if (response.results.length) {
                        const graphic = response.results.filter(function(result) {
                            if(result.graphic.layer === graphicsLayer){
                                layerView.highlight(result.graphic);
                            }
                            return result.graphic.layer === graphicsLayer;
                        })[0].graphic;

                        if(highlight) {
                            console.log("highlighted");
                            highlight.remove();
                        }
                        // highlight all features belonging to the same hurricane as the feature
                        // returned from the hitTest
                        highlight = layerView.highlight(graphic);
                    } else {
                        // remove the highlight if no features are
                        // returned from the hitTest
                        highlight.remove();
                        highlight = null;
                    }
                }
            });
    });
```

I even tried creating functions that change the symbol on those polygon graphics, but to no success.
I think, that the else statement at the end is never executed.  Which means, that the hitTest almost always returns a result. I debugged this a little and I saw, that the results are streets, buildings and such. After filtering those results I get the correct graphics I wish to highlight. However, layerView.highlight(graphic) doesn't work. This is how I create my mapView:

```
view = new MapView({
            container: "viewDiv",
            map: map,
            center: center, // longitude, latitude
            zoom: 15,
            highlightOptions: {
                color: "orange"
            }
        });
```

When I take the hovered graphic and change its' symbol to orange, it gets highlighted, but doesn't get unhighlighted once I unhover the element (since the else{} statement is almost never executed). Can anyone explain why hitTest always returns a result and why .highlight() doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you are highlighting when `highlight` is null, that is the first hit at start or after no feature is hit. You need to change,

```
if (highlight) {
  return;
}
```

for

```
if (highlight) {
  highlight.remove();
}
```

That means, if there is a feature highlighted, then remove it. Then highlight the new hit feature.

`hitTest`

> returns the topmost feature from each layer that intersects the
>   specified screen coordinates

([ArcGIS Doc - MapView hitTest](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-MapView.html#hitTest)).

Here is the code modification from the ArcGIS example,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"
    />
    <title>Access features with pointer events - 4.14</title>

    <style>
      html,
      body,
      #viewDiv {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>

    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/esri/themes/light/main.css"
    />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.14/"></script>

    <script>
      require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"
      ], function(Map, MapView, FeatureLayer) {
        const hurricanesLayer = new FeatureLayer({
          url:
            "https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Hurricanes/MapServer/1",
          outFields: ["*"]
        });
        const map = new Map({
          basemap: "dark-gray",
          layers: [hurricanesLayer]
        });
        const view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map,
          center: [-61.125537, 35.863534],
          zoom: 4,
          highlightOptions: {
            color: "orange"
          }
        });
        view
          .when()
          .then(function() {
            return hurricanesLayer.when();
          })
          .then(function(layer) {
            const renderer = layer.renderer.clone();
            renderer.symbol.width = 4;
            renderer.symbol.color = [128, 128, 128, 0.8];
            layer.renderer = renderer;
            // Set up an event handler for pointer-down (mobile)
            // and pointer-move events (mouse)
            // and retrieve the screen x, y coordinates
            return view.whenLayerView(layer);
          })
          .then(function(layerView) {
            view.on("pointer-move", eventHandler);
            view.on("pointer-down", eventHandler);

            function eventHandler(event) {
              // the hitTest() checks to see if any graphics in the view
              // intersect the x, y coordinates of the pointer
              view.hitTest(event).then(getGraphics);
            }

            let highlight, currentYear, currentName;

            function getGraphics(response) {
              // the topmost graphic from the hurricanesLayer
              if (response.results.length) {
                const features = response.results.filter(function(result) {
                  return result.graphic.layer === hurricanesLayer;
                });
                if (features.length) {
                  const graphic = features[0].graphic;
                  if (highlight) {
                    highlight.remove();
                  }
                  highlight = layerView.highlight(graphic);
                  return;
                }
              }
              // remove the highlight if no features, of the layer, are
              // returned from the hitTest
              highlight.remove();
              highlight = null;
            }
          });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The items are never highlighted

Comment: Okay, I changed the arcgis version to 4.14 and now at least the highlighting on hover works. However when the cursor moves past the element, the highlight doesn't disappear. Right now if I hover over two elements, they both are highlighted and they stay that way.

Comment: Now I'm back at square one. After some more debugging, it looksl ike the else{} statement isn't executed. Now what happens, is when I hover over the elements, I highlight, unhighlight, highlight and it stays highlighted. Then, when it should unhighlight for the last time, when I don't hit the required layer, it doesn't.

Comment: The `else` is executed when no feature is hit. This is actually pretty easy to check, just highlight a feature and then slowly move to "no feature". If you move the mouse quickly outside the map, let say after you highlight a feature close to the edge, then it may stay highlight, that is because you did not give "time" to test the hit.

Comment: Your code was good, but I needed to modify it. The problem is, that even though I'm not hitting a graphics layer, when I move my mouse, the respose.results.length is almost never 0. So I had to go through the results before the if() statement to check if the results had my expected layer(graphicsLayer) which contains all of the polygons I'm highlighting. By doing that check, the else statement is excecuted and the polygons are unhighlighted once the mouse exits them.

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the check you mention, if it is correct accept the answer for future viewers. Glad it help you!.

Comment: You see, the const features in your case are 100% the correct layer because they were filtered. Since most of the time there is going to be 1-2 layers under the cursor, you can run a check whether there even IS a layer of our type in that array. So I would run the check that you did before the if(response.results.length) by iterating through the response.results. Then if there are results (there are some kind of layers), but the layer we are looking for isn't there, we simply remove the highlight. If there are, we take the layer we found and then highlight the selected graphic.